# Pitch estimation using the autocorrelation method

Tags: matlab, autocorrelation, pitch, speech, fundamental-frequency

I have the following code:

```
// input: speech segment
[y,Fs,bits]= wavread('/media/A03036C33036A068/scilab/30msec_voiced.wav');
max_value=max(abs(y));
y=y/max_value;
t=(1/Fs:1/Fs:(length(y)/Fs))*1000;
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(t,y);
xtitle('A 30 millisecond segment of speech','time in milliseconds');
sum1=0;autocorrelation=0;
for l=0:(length(y)-1)
    sum1=0;
    for u=1:(length(y)-l)
        s=y(u)*y(u+l);
        sum1=sum1+s;
    end
    autocor(l+1)=sum1;
end
kk=(1/Fs:1/Fs:(length(autocor)/Fs))*1000;
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(kk,autocor);
xtitle('Autocorrelation of the 30 millisecond segment of speech','time in milliseconds');
auto=autocor(21:160);
max1=0;
for uu=1:140
    if(auto(uu)>max1)
        max1=auto(uu);
        sample_no=uu;
    end
end
pitch_period_To=(20+sample_no)*(1/Fs)
pitch_freq_Fo=1/pitch_period_To
```

In this, I am not getting the meaning of `pitch_period_To=(20+sample_no)*(1/Fs)`. Why did they add 20?

Answer (score 3):

An offset of 20 samples is added as 8 lines above (`auto=autocor(21:160)`) this offset is cut away from the autocorrelation sequence. In the line you mention, this offset has therefore to be considered.

This is done in order to cut away the first maximum (at time lags around zero) and avoid pitch errors caused by picking a delay value that does not make sense for the task of fundamental frequency estimation.

(By the way, your code does not perform *pitch* estimation but *fundamental frequency* estimation. There's a difference between these two terms as *pitch* relates to a perceptual property of a tone while *fundamental frequency* is a technical property - [Wikipedia on "Pitch"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_(music)).)